# how to match two table column data and count the unmatched rows of the first table

Tags: sql-server

```
Tbl_cdr(ano,starttime)
Tbl_User(id,mobileno)
```

I want to count the rows from `Tbl_cdr` with condition omitting the rows (when `ano = mobileno`) and group by `starttime`.

any help ,Plz...

Comment: What?!?! Can you try to rephrase that? I don't understand what you're looking for, sorry....

Comment: How is ano related here? are you joining tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*), c.StartTime
  from Tbl_cdr     c
left join Tbl_User u  on c.ano = u.mobileno
where u.id is null
group by c.StartTime
```

Comment: Tbl_cdr(ano,starttime)
Tbl_User(id,mobileno,registrationstate)                                               Thanks @datagod.u r awesome.if i want to give another condition from Tbl_user where registrationstate=1 then what will do?i,hv tried with this but wrong result..                             select Convert(varchar(10),c.StartTime,103) as Date,count(*)As TotalAttempts,
(select Count(*) from tbl_User u where u.registrationstate='1') as NewActivation
from Tbl_cdr     c
left join Tbl_User u  on c.ano = u.mobileno
where u.id is null
group by Convert(varchar(10),c.StartTime,103)

Answer (score 3):

```
select c.starttime, count(*)
from Tbl_cdr c
where not exists (select 1 from Tbl_User u where u.mobileno = c.ano)
group by c.starttime
```